# Structure of a group acting on a Hilbert space

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, hilbert-spaces, infinite-dimensional-manifolds, hilbert-manifolds

Assume a group $G$ acts faithfully by isometries on a separable infinite dimensional Hilbert space $H$ in such a way that the orbits are closed and the quotient $H/G$ is isometric to a finite dimensional Riemannian manifold.

Edit after YCor comment: Is there a natural way to equip $G$ with a topology so that it is an infinite dimensional Lie Group with a Lie Algebra?

Comment: $G$ can be a large discrete group, say acting transitively.

Comment: Hi YCor. Could you please describe an example with that property? I haven't been able to construct one.

Comment: Endow $G=H$ with the discrete topology, and let it act by translations on $H$. So the quotient is a point, and $G$ is a 0-dimensional Lie group. This is not an interesting example, probably additional hypotheses would be needed to discard it, and motivating examples could help then.

Comment: Your addition doesn't help resolve YCor's comment, take $H = H_1 \oplus H_1$ and $G = H_1 \oplus H_1^\delta$, the first term $H_1$ with the usual topology and the second with the discrete topology, considered as an additive group.

Comment: Hello Mike. If one uses the group of all translations, it could be equipped with the pointwise convergence topology and then it becomes homeomorphic to the Hilbert space.

Comment: Ah, "to equip $G$ with a topology", I misread. I am still sure this is too wild to give a good answer to but I do not have an immediate example.